# How to get oAuth2 tokenValue from Google login

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Couldn't get the tokenValue from Google login

I'm trying to use oAuth login through Google and successfully get the OAuth2AuthenticationToken from Google. Please see below picture.

I would like to save the token value into Redis to keep the login status in my website. However, I couldn't find the method to retrieve the tokenValue in the Principal > idToken. Is there any method to get it?

[image: OAuth2AuthenticationToken from Google]

Controller

`@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController {

```
@GetMapping
public Map<String, Object> login(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token){
    return token.getPrincipal().getAttributes();
}
```

}`